# Dragging UIView sets origin coordinates back to (0, 0)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIView` which i can drag, once i stop dragging  and start to drag the `UIView` again the coordinates of the `UIView` are set back to `0` even when i dragged the `UIView` to a specific location.

How would i get its proper location when the `UIView` is set lets say `(x,y)` to `(100,100)`?

The code below just allow you to drag the `UIView`

```
-(void)move:(id)sender {

[[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];

CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view.superview];
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];


[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(translation.y*4, translation.y*10, 320, 480)];
[uiWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320-self.view.frame.origin.x, (320-self.view.frame.origin.x)/2)];
[uiWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ResizeVideo('down', %0.0f, %0.0f)",320-self.view.frame.origin.x,uiWebView.frame.size.height]];

if(self.view.frame.origin.y > 0 && self.view.frame.origin.y < 400){

}
else{
    CGPoint localPoint = [self.view bounds].origin;
    CGPoint basePoint = [self.view convertPoint:localPoint toView:nil];
    if(basePoint.y < 0){
        NSLog(@"%0.0f",self.view.frame.origin.y);
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [uiWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320-self.view.frame.origin.x, (320-self.view.frame.origin.x)/2)];
        [uiWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ResizeVideo('down', %0.0f, %0.0f)",320-self.view.frame.origin.x,uiWebView.frame.size.height]];
    }
    if(self.view.frame.origin.y > 400){
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 400, 320, 480)];
        [uiWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 80)];
        [uiWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ResizeVideo('down', %0.0f, %0.0f)",320-self.view.frame.origin.x,uiWebView.frame.size.height]];
    }
}

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    if(self.view.frame.origin.y > 200){

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.35];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        //[[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(200, 100)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 400, 320, 480)];
        [uiWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 80)];         [UIView commitAnimations];
        [uiWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ResizeVideo('down', %0.0f, %0.0f)",160.0,80.0]];
        outOfBounds1 = false;
        outOfBounds2 = false;

    }

    if(self.view.frame.origin.y < 200){

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.35];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        //[[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 72)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [self.view setFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480))];
        [uiWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 144)];            [UIView commitAnimations];
        [uiWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ResizeVideo('down', %0.0f, %0.0f)",320.0,144.0]];
        outOfBounds1 = false;
        outOfBounds2 = false;
    }
}


NSLog(outOfBounds1 ? @"Yes" : @"No");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace line:

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(translation.y*4, translation.y*10, 320, 480)];
```

with:

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + translation.y*4,
                               self.view.frame.origin.y + translation.y*10, 
                               320, 
                               480)];
```

Basically you are always setting the frame to the initial translation values. The fix is to add the translation values to the current position og the view.

Let me know if it helped.